# Apache proxy returning 403 forbidden

Tags: apache-http-server, centos

I'm trying to set up a home page where I can redirect my requests to others servers with a proxy so I have a single point of entry. I used to have this setup working properly on a windows machine running WAMP. I made the switch to Apache on CentOS7 and since, I'm having this issue. Here's my landing page:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName myhost.duckdns.org
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/panel

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/myhost.duckdns.org/privkey.pem
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/myhost.duckdns.org/cert.pem
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/myhost.duckdns.org/chain.pem
    SetEnvIf User-Agent ".*MSIE.*" nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown


    <Directory /var/www/html/panel>
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from myips
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Authorised Users Only"
    AuthUserFile .htpasswd
    Satisfy Any
    Require valid-user
    </Directory>
```

And here's the proxypass

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerName sickbeard.my.to

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/sickbeard.my.to/privkey.pem
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/sickbeard.my.to/cert.pem
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/sickbeard.my.to/chain.pem
    SetEnvIf User-Agent ".*MSIE.*" nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown

    <Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from myips
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Authorised Users Only"
    AuthUserFile .htpasswd
    Satisfy Any
    Require valid-user
    </Proxy>
    ProxyPass / http://192.168.0.170:8081/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.0.170:8081/
</VirtualHost>
```

I can reach the main page without problem and I can reach sickbeard using the IP or the hostname but using the hostname gives me the 403.

Comment: Allow from myips - so i guess you have the ip there but not the hostname..

Comment: @Setekh Yes, there's 4 ips there

Comment: Can you try to add Allow from FQDN ..

Comment: @Setekh Just tried, same thing :/

Comment: hmmm do you have any Rewrites for blocking .. like RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} microsoft\.com [NC,OR] 
RewriteRule .* - [F]
:D it may have some error there

Comment: @Setekh I don't have any in my vhosts.conf, should i look elsewhere?

Comment: @Setekh Found it! It was blocked by the mod_security module! I should've checked the logs first... -_-

Comment: write an answer so if someone else is having similar issue. It is ok for you to write both question and answer, and you can OK it after 24 hours i think.

Comment: @Gab Please read [Can I answer my own question?](http://superuser.com/help/self-answer). You might want to convert your comment into an answer ;)

Answer (score 2):

Found it! It was blocked by the mod_security module! I should've checked the logs first.

I disabled that module in httpd.conf. I read a bit on the subject and for what i'm doing, this module was clearly an overkil.

Answer (score 2):

This is an older post, but hopefully this can still help people who find it in the future. The issue is indeed with your mod_security module, but only because your module is doing what you told it to do in your configuration. The lines that are giving you trouble are these two:

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
```

The operator `Order deny,allow` instructs Apache to process your deny rules before your allow rules. Since you have `Deny from all`, Apache is denying everything before it is told to allow something. A quick fix for this issue is to change `Order deny,allow` to `Order allow,deny`. Then Apache will allow the hosts you've specified before denying all others.